# PHP follow/unfollow buttons are working but refresh needed to see the results

Tags: php, html, sql

I have created a follow/unfollow system where the user can follow a different user, and if he is following him he can later on decide to unfollow him. The sql/mysql inserting and deleting database content depending on the button clicked is working. However due to PHP dynamic data the user needs to refresh to view the corrosponding output (whether following/follow). How would I need to go about to solve this problem?

This is both my functions used:

Function for unfollow

```
            //unfollow selected uploader if already following
            function unfollow($userid, $uploader_id){

            if(isset($_POST['unfollow'])){
            $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db');
                $userid = sanitize($userid);
                $uploader_id = sanitize($uploader_id);
                //prepare statement
                $stmt = $con ->prepare("DELETE FROM follow
        WHERE u_id = ? AND uploader_id = ?");
                $stmt -> bind_param("ss",$userid, $uploader_id);
                if($result = $stmt->execute()){
                }else{
                echo "failed to unfollow";  
                }
            }
            }
```

This is the function for the follow

```
        //use this function to follow an uploader
        function follow($userid, $uploader_id){

            if(isset($_POST['follow']))
            {
            if(logged_in()){

            if($userid != $uploader_id){
                $con = mysqli_connect('localhost', 'root', '', 'db');
                $userid = sanitize($userid);
                $uploader_id = sanitize($uploader_id);
                //prepare statement
                $stmt = $con ->prepare("INSERT INTO follow (u_id, uploader_id) VALUES (?, ?)");
                $stmt -> bind_param("ss",$userid, $uploader_id);
                    if($result = $stmt->execute()){ 
                    }
                    else{
                        echo "Failed to follow";    
                    }
                }// users cant follow themselves


            }//if not logged in do this
            else{
                echo "<h1 style='clear:left;font-size:15px; color:red;'>You have to be logged in to follow</h1>";   
                }
            }
        }
```

html/php button depending on if user is following or not:

```
        //if the user is not logged in just display a button that send him/her to the login page if clicked 
        if(!logged_in()){
        ?>
        <form id="follow" action="login.php">
         <button style="float:left;"  class="follow_btn" type="submit">Follow</button>
        </form>
        <?php 
        }else if($uploaderid == $session_user_id){

        }
         //if the user is not following the uploader show the follow button
         else if(!is_following($session_user_id, $uploaderid)){
         ?>
         <form id="follow" method="POST" action="<?php follow($session_user_id, $uploaderid) ?>">
         <button style="float:left;" id="follow_btn" class="follow_btn" type="submit" name="follow">Follow</button>
         </form>
         <?php 

         //else show the unfollow button
         }else{
         ?>
         <form id="follow" method="POST" action="<?php unfollow($session_user_id, $uploaderid) ?>">
         <button style="float:left;" id="unfollow_btn" class="follow_btn" type="submit" name="unfollow">Following</button>
         </form>

         <?php
         }

         ?>
```

Comment: You can use AJAX calls to show the follower count.

Comment: do you want to just refresh page on submit? add onClick="window.location.reload()" to button tag

Comment: @brad I tried that it doesnt work, i think the php is running first ignoring the reload request.

Comment: does it show correctly if you manually refresh page? if it does you could add seperate Jquery script to reload page on either button press

Answer (score 0):

try this-> forceget will make it reload from server

put this somewhere below form I think syntax and brackets are correct you dont have pure html might be hard to check on jsfiddle

```
<script>
$( document ).ready(function() {

$('#follow_btn').click(function() {
    location.reload(forceGet);
  });

$('#unfollow_btn').click(function() {
    location.reload(forceGet);
  });
});
</script>
```

you might need to wrap click events in set timeout function to avoid reloading page too soon

```
setTimeout(function() {
   $('#follow_btn').click(function() {
        location.reload(forceGet);
      });
}, 300);
```

Comment: Hi brad, great example unfortunately its not working.

Comment: probably not the case but it happens sometimes did you include jquery script link? Also does a manually refresh fix it?

Comment: Manual refresh does fix it, but this method is not actually refreshing the page (after the php work has been run)

Comment: even wrapped in the set timeout? The php should not take very long at all. If wrapped in the set timeout does not work then I am out of what I usually do to fix things like this